Greek has the word for tin (kassiteros), Arabic has the word (القصدير or alqasdir). What other languages have similar or related words for tin?
Just looking for similar words for tin in other languages.
Did the Arabs get their word from the Greeks or do they both get it from a pre-greek source?

According to Wiktionary, the Arabic word is a loan from Ancient Greek (via Aramaic), but the ultimate origin is uncertain. Sanskrit also borrowed it (perhaps via Arabic). Seems to be a bit of a Wanderwört, which is far from unheard of with names of metals.

According to Beekes the Greek word has the stock pre-Greek form,  and its wanderings may have originated in the Zagros mountains, its source...

You'll find to be "similar or related words" all the descendants of the Greek one.
Greek: κασσίτερος (kassíteros)
→ Aramaic: קְסְטִירָא (qəsṭīrā), קַסִּיטְרָא (qassīṭrā)
    → Arabic: قَصْدِير (qaṣdīr)
→ Serbo-Croatian: kòsitar
→ Slovene: kosítər

Romanian is not mentioned, but it has it too: cositor, which lead to the verb a cositori = to cover with tin. It also led to the name of a category of Romani traditional metallurgists (coppersmiths) specialized in producing metalware covered with tin: costorari - țigani costorari. More on that context here.
